# The element 'buildProviders' cannot be defined below the application level in <buildProviders> tag

Tags: asp.net, rdlc

I deploy my asp.net web application and  face this error

The element 'buildProviders' cannot be defined below the application level.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open IIS manager.
2. right click your application directory
3. Click on 'convert to Application'
4. Refresh application directory
5. You are good to go
6. Check on browse

Answer (score 0):

In my case i had the same application duplicated in the iis. One in the Root folder and another one in a subfolder